# Reputation formatting

Tags: discussion, markdown

I know this is a bit picky but I'm pretty sure the format of the reputation score on the user details screen has changed.

All other instances of reputation are formatted properly but the reputation on the user details screen looks like this:

[image]

Could you add the comma back in please?  I am guessing that this happened when the link to your privileges was added in?

Alternatively, it may be that it was never formatted properly and I seem to be [living in my own dream world](http://www.siriusarcadegames.com/game/1720/Robot_Unicorn_Attack.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't fit in Jon Skeet's inevitable one million reps as

## 1,000,000

And it's even getting a little crowded with just the 100k users. So I pulled it.

Comment: Sometimes it feels like Jon Skeet's and Nick Craver's reputation increases on the same basis as Google increase their available storage for Gmail accounts.

Comment: Classic scaling problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [10,360 commas](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/12864/number-of-users-with-1k-rep) stolen from the 1k+ users.

[image: commas]

Comment: +1 Well as you have owned up to stealing them, could you put them back please?  You have until tomorrow or I'm calling in the cops.